# jQuery fails to attach an event handler to an object when called inside a coffeescript constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, event-handling, coffeescript

I am using jQuery to dispatch events between multiple javascript objects.

I have a Coffeescript class, that attaches a custom event handler to an object in its constructor :

```
class Player 

  constructor: ->
    @queue = new MediaQueue() # custom queue class
    $(@queue).on 'purged', (event, purged) => 
      media.destroy() for media in purged
      @fillQueue()
```

**My problem is that this handler is never called.**

Moreover, inside chrome's console, when I try :

```
$._data(player.queue, 'events')
```

I get `undefined`.

**The weird part is that attaching that handler anywhere outside the constructor does work.**

Still in chrome console :

```
$(player.queue).on('purged', function(event, purged){ 
  console.log('purged',purged) 
});
player.queue.purge();

=> purged, > Array[2]
```

It even works if the binding logic is called *after* the constructor :

```
class Player 

  constructor: ->
    @queue = new MediaQueue() 

  bindQueue: ->
    $(@queue).on 'purged', (event, purged) => 
       media.destroy() for media in purged
       @fillQueue()
```

then :

```
var player = new Player();
player.bindQueue()
player.queue.purge() # the handler gets called as it should
```

I suspect a variable scope issue. Why can't I attach this handler inside the constructor ?

**UPDATE**

I found a weird workaround.

Here's how I instantiate that player :

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('[data-somenamespace-player]').each ->
    # the player is actually bound to a container
    # I just shortened the constructor code for simplicity's sake
    @somenamespace_player = new Player(@)
```

If I try to bind the handler like this, it doesn't work :

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('[data-somenamespace-player]').each ->
    @somenamespacePlayer = new Player(@)
    $(@somenamespacePlayer.queue).on 'purged', (event, purged) =>
      media.destroy() for media in purged
      @somenamespacePlayer.fillQueue()
```

... but it *does work* when i use a timeout :

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('[data-somenamespace-player]').each ->
    @somenamespacePlayer = new Player(@)
    setTimeout =>
                 $(@somenamespacePlayer.queue).on 'purged', (event, purged) =>
                   media.destroy() for media in purged
                   @somenamespacePlayer.fillQueue()
               ,
               5000
```

How could this be ? Could it be something relative to my Queue class ?

**UPDATE**

There's something strange that I noticed in the debugger. I set a breakpoint inside the constructor then tried this :

```
$(this)
=> []
```

I also set a breakpoint inside one the first queue method that is used, same deal :

```
$(this)
=> []
```

then, after resuming the execution and waiting a bit :

```
$(player.queue)
=> [>MediaQueue]
```

Moreover, when inside the MediaQueue constructor, I noticed a strange behavior (actual compiled js):

```
function MediaQueue() {
      var _this = this; // if I try $(this) in the console at this stage, i get
                        // a TypeError : cannot read property length of undefined

      this._medias = [];      // idem at this stage, just before assignment
      this._currentIndex = 0; // now $(this) => []
}
```

I suspect that something is going on that is beyond my understanding of how javascript works...

Comment: Have you looked at the CoffeeScript compiler's output, the actual JavaScript that the compiler produces?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, nothing strange here

Comment: @mu no, it's a typo, I'll fix it. This is not the actual code, I shortened it.

Comment: update : using a timeout seems to work. WTF ?

Comment: Does it still work if you drop the timeout to zero? Is there something DOM-based going when you `$(@queue).on(...)`? This is starting to smell like a "something's not in the DOM when you think it is" problem.

Comment: the queue is a POJO that stores other POJOS (custom 'media' class). However, when i push objects inside the queue, I also bind them to <video> elements created on the fly. I'll try to set the timeout to 0 and get back to you.

Comment: @muistooshort no, it doesn't work when the timeout is 0. Also, in my original constructor, I bind a bunch of other controllers to some containers after creating the queue, don't know if this matters

Comment: another update, and I'm getting more and more confused...

Comment: Any chance of seeing a minimal but functional demo?

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for investigating this. I tried to put up a (non)functionnal demo on JSFiddle, and could not reproduce the bug, so I guess something's wrong with my MediaQueue code. Unfortunately, I cannot divulge the entire source now, as it does not belong to me (job related). I'll keep trying to reproduce the bug on JSFiddle and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears I made a stupid mistake...

Because of this :

```
class MediaQueue 

  Object.defineProperties @prototype,
                          length: -> @_medias.length
```

jQuery is unable to attach event handlers to `MediaQueue` objects *when the queue is empty* (which explains the `setTimeout` workaround).

I don't know exactly why, but it sure was not very clever to create such property in the first place...

(*edit : the reason is that $.each considers objects with a length property as iterable, and tries to attach the handler on every property of the object instead of the object itself...*)

**To sum up : DO NOT create a `length` property on objects when you want to trigger events on them with jQuery.**

**EDIT**

Seems that I was not alone to bite the bullet - someone [filed this as an issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14990) on the jQuery Bug Tracker, only to see it closed with reason **not a bug - this is intended behavior of $.each**.